# acess specific field graphql react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql

My code looks like this:

```js
interface MutationProps {
    username: string;
    Mutation: any;
  }
  export const UseCustomMutation: React.FC<MutationProps> | any = (username: any, Mutation: DocumentNode ) => {
    const [functionForDoingAction, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(
      Mutation,
      {
        variables: {
          username,
        },
      }
    );
  
    useEffect(() => {
      // fn trigger for change data
      functionForDoingAction({
        variables: {
          username: username,
        },
      });
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
    }, []);
  
    if (loading) return "loading...";
  
    if (error) return `Submission error! ${error.message}`;
  
    return data;
  };
  export const DisplayUser = () => {
  const GET_USER = gql`
    mutation GetUser($username: String!) {
      getUser(username: $username) {
        pfp
        username
        password
        age
        CurrentLive
        ismod
        description
        fullname
      }
    }
  `;
  const { username }: { username: any } = useParams();
  const MyData = UseCustomMutation(username, GET_USER);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(MyData));
```

I wanna a access `MyData.pfp` but it gives me this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'pfp' of undefined

if it matters when i go on e.g. `localhost:3000/user/dakepake` variable MyData looks like this:

> UserProfile.tsx:39 {"getUser":{"pfp":""https://i.pinimg.com/564x/65/25/a0/6525a08f1df98a2e3a545fe2ace4be47.jpg"","username":""dakepake"","password":""mohikanac10"","age":14,"CurrentLive":"""","ismod":false,"description":""this user dont have a bio yet"","fullname":""damjan alimpic"","__typename":"GetUserResponse"}}

How can I fix this?

Comment: I added some more data, is it good now? @RyanLe

Comment: can you paste the output of console.log(JSON.stringify(MyData));

Comment: UserProfile.tsx:39 {"getUser":{"pfp":""https://i.pinimg.com/564x/65/25/a0/6525a08f1df98a2e3a545fe2ace4be47.jpg"","username":""dakepake"","password":""mohikanac10"","age":14,"CurrentLive":"""","ismod":false,"description":""this user dont have a bio yet"","fullname":""damjan alimpic"","__typename":"GetUserResponse"}}

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this on my own , i just replaced MyData.pfp whit MyData.getUser.pfp and now its working